# Is there a tool that will allow me to read/write test a drive?

Tags: hard-disk

Meaning test writing to every single byte on the drive even on a drive with data on it while preserving the data.  Something that supports a nvme ssd.
Something I can run from a linux bootable usb.

I know I can use dd to read a drive or fill a drive.  but ideally, a tool that goes through byte by byte one at a time so I don't have to store the entire drive somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

[`badblocks`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Badblocks) can do this, but it’s rather slow on modern drives. Its write tests might even end up doing more harm than good on SSD-style drives, given that it writes blocks that are far smaller than most drives’ native blocks.

In any case doing a full write test on a modern drive is probably not that useful any more — drives are very good at handling errors that occur while writing. Running a full read test and/or a full SMART test, and watching for sectors being remapped during normal use, should be sufficient to weed out early failures.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware badblocks could do this.  I'll give it a try.   Over time, blocks that haven't been written to become harder to read thus taking more time reducing performance.  A rewrite restores the performance.  Doing it once in a while shouldn't affect the overall wear that much.